# How to decode Log.Data in Go

Tags: go-ethereum, logs, golang, encoding

I'm fetching the logs using `client.SubscribeFilterLogs`. The event parameters are encoded in `types.Log.Data`. How can I decode it in `go`?

Comment: Yes, the [go-ethereum](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum) (the geth libraries) package received the contribution to add Event unpacking. I will write more about it in the answer below.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[go-ethereum abi](https://gowalker.org/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/accounts/abi) package in Oct 2017 got the update to unpack event output. Initially it was only able to unpack method output.

All functionality is delivered through the `abi.ABI` object. To use it you need to have Event ABI (JSON string). Then use [func (abi *ABI) UnmarshalJSON](https://gowalker.org/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/accounts/abi#ABI_UnmarshalJSON) to construct the `ABI` object. From there you can use the `Unpack` method using `Data` from your log object.

Bear in mind that indexed attributes go into log `Topic` rather than `Data`.

For more usage details you can follow this examples:

- [ERC20 Event structure](https://bitbucket.org/sweetbridge/oracles/src/efe3a3c6e0e68b64f03238c705583d7fc61855d5/go-lib/liquidity/events.go?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default#events.go-52)
- [ERC20 Event test](https://bitbucket.org/sweetbridge/oracles/src/efe3a3c6e0e68b64f03238c705583d7fc61855d5/go-lib/liquidity/events_test.go?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default)

NOTE:
In the current implementation (2017-11-29) there is a bug with indexed attributes. I've submitted a [PR](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/pull/15452#pullrequestreview-76525306) for that and still waiting for the final approval.

Answer (score 6):

Here's a full code example for anyone who's still confused (thanks to @Robert Zaremba's answer)

```
package main

import (
    "context"

    "log"
    "math/big"
    "strings"

    "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum"
    "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/accounts/abi"
    "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/common"

    "github.com/myorg/myrepo/go-contracts/token"
    "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/core/types"
)


func main() {
    contractAddress := common.HexToAddress("0x0d8775f648430679a709e98d2b0cb6250d2887ef")

    query := ethereum.FilterQuery{
        Addresses: []common.Address{contractAddress},
    }

    var ch = make(chan types.Log)
    ctx := context.Background()

    sub, err := Client.SubscribeFilterLogs(ctx, query, ch)

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    tokenAbi, err := abi.JSON(strings.NewReader(string(token.TokenABI)))

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    for {
        select {
        case err := <-sub.Err():
            log.Fatal(err)
        case eventLog := <-ch:
            var transferEvent struct {
                From  common.Address
                To    common.Address
                Value *big.Int
            }

            err = tokenAbi.Unpack(&transferEvent, "Transfer", eventLog.Data)

            if err != nil {
                log.Println("Failed to unpack")
                continue
            }

            transferEvent.From = common.BytesToAddress(eventLog.Topics[1].Bytes())
            transferEvent.To = common.BytesToAddress(eventLog.Topics[2].Bytes())

            log.Println("From", transferEvent.From.Hex())
            log.Println("To", transferEvent.To.Hex())
            log.Println("Value", transferEvent.Value)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: One question: how do you know if the data contains a Transfer event, or a Approval event??? Because, you can receive both, or you can even receive other events, like `burn` or `mint` , so how do you know in advance which type of event do you have to unpack?

Comment: @Nulik great question; so topic[0] will be the event signature which is `keccak256(eventName(arg1,arg2))` so if it's a transfer event then topic[0] will be `keccak256(Transfer(address,address,uint256))` => `ddf252ad1be2c89b69c2b068fc378daa952ba7f163c4a11628f55a4df523b3ef`. So in short: you know the event type by filtering by topic[0] which is the hash of the event signature. Check out this Ethereum Development with Go guide for examples https://goethereumbook.org/

Comment: @Nulik here's an example event log of a transfer event https://etherscan.io/tx/0xdb192735df87a8b89df52fa0d0391fa6b53636c81c9dda954e3f30849e9a5c7b#eventlog . As you can see topic[0] is `keccak256(Transfer(address,address,uint256))` => `ddf252ad1be2c89b69c2b068fc378daa952ba7f163c4a11628f55a4df523b3ef`

Comment: @Nulik here's an example event log of an approval event https://etherscan.io/tx/0xd43ccc6002c2ccccc7219e2ac67665c1e2ac7dbd2918f28f0b8eb90721a17666#eventlog . As you can see topic[0] is `keccak256(Approval(address,address,uint256))` => `8c5be1e5ebec7d5bd14f71427d1e84f3dd0314c0f7b2291e5b200ac8c7c3b925`

Comment: Thanks, I have got it now. BTW, do you know of any other standard events? Transfer() and Approval() are the usual, but many tokens add minting or burning events. Do you know of any other events that are becoming standard too for erc20 tokens?

Comment: @Nulik not sure, check out popular ethereum EIPS https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues

Comment: may I ask what `geth` version was used with this code?

Comment: @Nulik `Version: 1.8.10-stable`

Comment: Thanks. This explains why my 1.7.2 isn't working. The abi.Unpack() doesn't manage events yet. I guess this feature was added from 1.8

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I did it using the ABI:

```
path, _ := filepath.Abs("./resources/etherdelta.abi")
file, err := ioutil.ReadFile(path)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("Failed to read file:", err)
}
edabi, err := abi.JSON(strings.NewReader(string(file)))
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("Invalid abi:", err)
}
var orderStruct struct {
    TokenGet   common.Address
    AmountGet  *big.Int
    TokenGive  common.Address
    AmountGive *big.Int
    Expires    *big.Int
    Nonce      *big.Int
    User       common.Address
}
err = edabi.Unpack(&orderStruct, "Order", log.Data)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("Failed to unpack:", err)
}
fmt.Println("TokenGet:", orderStruct.TokenGet.Hex())
fmt.Println("AmountGet:", orderStruct.AmountGet.Hex())
```

Answer (score 0):

```
data := common.TrimLeftZeroes(log.Data)
hex := common.Bytes2Hex(data)
hex = TrimLeftZeroes(hex)
if hex != "" {
    erc20Amount, err := hexutil.DecodeBig("0x" + hex)
}



func TrimLeftZeroes(hex string) string {
    idx := 0
    for ; idx < len(hex); idx++ {
        if hex[idx] != '0' {
            break
        }
    }
    return hex[idx:]
}
```

Comment: Explain your code.

Comment: This is the answer to the question, dont be kidding me.